# Usage of (Where IN) clause of SQL

Tags: sql, excel

I am trying to search and display the following questions mentioned below in the code as excel output.
As my excel spreadsheet has **LABEL** and **DATA** as the two columns, the questions comes under the Column named LABEL, while its relevant YES/NO answers comes under column named DATA.

The first three questions should be displayed in the excel sheet, only if its answer is 'NO' !

```
WHERE Label IN ('Is the price adequate? ' AND Data='No',
                'Were the proper measures taken prior?   ' AND Data='No',
                'Is the incident reported?  ' AND Data='No', 
                'Did the both prices match?' ,
                'Learning Methods',
                'Next actions Required','Final feedback')
```

The above code when executed throws up all the questions in the output no matter if it is Yes/No

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do, but you probably need to use a CASE expression.

Comment: Sort on a generated guid and update the top 10?

Comment: I have posted the actual query that I am working on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you need something like

```
WHERE 
    (
        Label IN ('Is the price adequate? ', 
                'Were the proper measures taken prior?   ', 
                'Is the incident reported?  '
             ) 
        AND Data='No'
    )
    or 
    (
        Label IN ('Did the both prices match?' ,
                  'Learning Methods',
                  'Next actions Required',
                  'Final feedback'
                  )
    )
```

Comment: This is selecting all the values under a column. I actually need only the values '30','40','50' and for '10' and '20' only if its answer is no

Comment: Hmm... It looks like I've missed something. Conditions should be united with `and` instead of `or` logical operator.

Comment: Changing operators from `or` to `and` cannot produce the same result, it's impossible.

Comment: I mean, it shows yes instead of no. It doesn't filters out the data instead show all the value in a column

Comment: I can't deduce what's going wrong at your side. Can you update your question with some data samples and desired results?

Comment: I have posted the actual query that I am working on in vba

Comment: I've updated anwser based on your updated question. and yes, it should be `or` there since now it is `IN` condition instead of `NOT IN` you've shown previously.